# How to test a Spring Cloud Function using message stream

Tags: spring-cloud-function

I'm currently attempting to port an existing Spring Cloud Stream app over to using Spring Cloud Function instead. When running the application, we use bindings to map from an input queue (either Kafka or IBMMQ). Messages sent on the queue are passed through a custom MessageConverter and then passed to our custom routing function.

In Spring Cloud Stream, the bindings allowed for direct access to the testing queues (via calling input()) for example, and one could simply send a message on that queue to start the process rolling.

What I'm trying to find is a similar mechanism for sending messages to the queue that the Spring Cloud Function is bound to. The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

I've seen how one can access the routingFunction via HTTP, but unfortunately, this bypasses my MessageConverter so I still can't really do an end-to-end test.

Has anyone got any ideas or pointers to how I might get this to work with Cloud Function?

Comment: have you been able to resolve that?